# How to set up a surface integral on a cylinder cut by planes?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Find the surface area of the piece of the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ cut off by the planes $z = 0$ and $y = z$ with $y \ge 0$ using surface integrals.

Can someone help me set up this surface integral or give me a hint on how to go about this?